# Как парсить участок кода <script type

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер, beautiful-soup

Задача: достать ссылку на картинку из кода, который выглядит так

```
 <script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"activity_counts":null,"config": __много кода__ "dimensions":{"height":1350,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/d60f1dbd5f2a609e6a653569a8a13a11/5B807715/t51.2885-15/e35/31297890_370834860094260_8326112321717927936_n.jpg"
```

Искомая ссылка лежит после тега "display_url".

Через BeautifulSoup не получилось. Может как-то через регулярные выражения можно?

Comment: Что значит «не получилось»? Должно прекрасно получаться

Comment: ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Ошибка сама по себе ничего не говорит, покажите код, который даёт эту ошибку

Answer (score 2):

soup нужен вам чтобы получить из кода страницы нужный тэг script.
содержимое этого тэга - это json объект.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

src = '<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"activity_counts":null,"config":"","dimensions":{"height":1350,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/d60f1dbd5f2a609e6a653569a8a13a11/5B807715/t51.2885-15/e35/31297890_370834860094260_8326112321717927936_n.jpg"}</script>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
script = soup.find('script') #здесь нужно указать доп.условия поиска именно вашего тега
json_text = re.findall('^s*window\._sharedData\s*=\s*({.*?})\s*\s*$', script.string, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)[0]
js = json.loads(json_text)
print(js['display_url'])
```